# Framework7 toggle component not being reactive

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I'm using Vue and Framework7 for an android app.

I have 4 toggles inside a list in which only one can be active at a time. Also, the only active toggle must be disabled so there will never be none active toggles.

My problem is that despite I change the `estado`variable, the changes seems to not react in the component.

The initial state works ok (estado === 0, first item loads checked and disabled). Further interactions with the other toggles does not produce expected results.

```
<template>
  <f7-page>
    <f7-navbar title="Gestión de pantalla" back-link="Back"></f7-navbar>
    <f7-list class="components-list searchbar-found">
      <f7-list-item title="Manual">
        <f7-toggle :disabled="estado === Estados.MANUAL" :checked="estado === Estados.MANUAL" @change="CambiarEstado(Estados.MANUAL)" slot="after"></f7-toggle>
      </f7-list-item>
      <f7-list-item title="Manual/Telepase">
        <f7-toggle :disabled="estado === Estados.MANUALTELEPASE" :checked="estado === Estados.MANUALTELEPASE" @change="CambiarEstado(Estados.MANUALTELEPASE)" slot="after"></f7-toggle>
      </f7-list-item>
      <f7-list-item title="Telepase">
        <f7-toggle :disabled="estado === Estados.TELEPASE" :checked="estado === Estados.TELEPASE" @change="CambiarEstado(Estados.TELEPASE)" slot="after"></f7-toggle>
      </f7-list-item>
      <f7-list-item title="Vía Cerrada">
        <f7-toggle :disabled="estado === Estados.CERRADO" :checked="estado === Estados.CERRADO" @change="CambiarEstado(Estados.CERRADO)" slot="after"></f7-toggle>
      </f7-list-item>
    </f7-list>
  </f7-page>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: function(){
            return {
                estado:0,
                Estados : {
                    MANUAL: 0,
                    MANUALTELEPASE: 1,
                    TELEPASE: 2,
                    CERRADO:3
                },
                manual_active:''
            }
        },
        methods:{
            CambiarEstado(estado_){
                this.estado = estado_;
            }
        }
  };
</script>
```

EDIT: seems that @change is being called twice when I click another toggle:

- Initial state is `estado` = 0 and toggle 0 checked
- I click toggle 3, which calls @change and sets estado to 3
- This triggers @change in toggle 0, which sets again `estado` to 0

Comment: You need to know whether the `change` is opening or closing. You only want to set `estado` when opening.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the method to the `<f7-list-item>` @click event. Despite not the exact same behaviour (clicks anywhere on the list item triggers the toggle, instead of only clicking in the toggle) this is ok for me.

```
<template>
  <f7-page>
    <f7-navbar title="Gestión de pantalla" back-link="Back"></f7-navbar>
    <f7-list class="components-list searchbar-found">
      <f7-list-item title="Manual" @click="CambiarEstado(Estados.MANUAL)">
        <f7-toggle :disabled="estado === Estados.MANUAL" :checked="estado === Estados.MANUAL"  slot="after"></f7-toggle>
      </f7-list-item>
      <f7-list-item title="Manual/Telepase" @click="CambiarEstado(Estados.MANUALTELEPASE)" >
        <f7-toggle :disabled="estado === Estados.MANUALTELEPASE" :checked="estado === Estados.MANUALTELEPASE" slot="after"></f7-toggle>
      </f7-list-item>
      <f7-list-item title="Telepase" @click="CambiarEstado(Estados.TELEPASE)" >
        <f7-toggle :disabled="estado === Estados.TELEPASE" :checked="estado === Estados.TELEPASE" slot="after"></f7-toggle>
      </f7-list-item>
      <f7-list-item title="Vía Cerrada" @click="CambiarEstado(Estados.CERRADO)">
        <f7-toggle :disabled="estado === Estados.CERRADO" :checked="estado === Estados.CERRADO"  slot="after"></f7-toggle>
      </f7-list-item>
    </f7-list>
  </f7-page>
</template>
```